# Not able to retrieve vimeo video details through API for paid account in vimeo

Tags: video, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to get vimeo video details for a particular user through vimeo api for paid account.

This is the code which I used for it and this is the version of vimeo class I am using Vimeo 1.2.3 (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/releases)

```
    $client_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $client_secret ='xxxxxxxxx';

    $access_token = 'xxxxxx'; 

    $lib = new Vimeo($client_id, $client_secret);   
    $lib->setToken($access_token);  
    $response = $lib->request('/me/videos', array('per_page' => 2), 'GET');

    $videos = $response['body']['data'];
    print_r($response);exit;
```

The issue here is,  for a normal test account its fetching the $response array value , where as if I try paid account credential details of vimeo its throwing the this error for $response

```
Array ( [body] => Array ( [error] => A valid user token must be passed. ) [status] => 401
```

Comment: You might want to mention the library you're using the Vimeo class from.

Comment: @johnh10 : This is the version of vimeo class I am using Vimeo 1.2.3 (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/releases)

Answer (score 0):

If the user has a private account, you will need to be that user to view information. Vimeo might be able to offer more direct support here, by looking up the user account and comparing it against your token.

Reach out to them at https://vimeo.com/help/contact

Comment: I got the login credentials and I found out the issue was access token given was generated for oauth and not for oauth2 and now I generated for oauth2 and its working fine.